# Regex pipe after square brackets

Tags: regex

I found a regex which i quite dont understand.

It looks like this:

```
([|)\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b(]|)
```

I do understand that it tries to match against some digits like 255.255 and that it should be a complete word.

But what are the "([|)" "(]|)" for? The square bracket and the pipe in the last one is also in the wrong order as it seems.

Comment: It's syntactically valid, but makes no sense. Must be a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

krackmoe, interestingly, there is no `([|)`: it is an optical illusion.

The regex engine does not see `([|)`

It sees `(` which opens capture Group 1, then it sees a character class `[|)\b(25[0-5]` which does not make a whole lot of sense for several reasons. For instance, `\b` matches the literal character "b", and the characters 2 and 5 are redundant with the range `0-5`.

So you are quite right not to understand it.

I presume the author wanted to put a word boundary there, but as it stands, it is a typo.

For reference, here is a token-by-token explanation of the regex. (Don't worry, I didn't type all that, it was automatically generated by RegexBuddy.)

```
* Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 `([|)\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)`
    * Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) `[|)\b(25[0-5]`
        * Match a single character present in the list below `[|)\b(25[0-5]`
            * A single character from the list “|)” `|)`
            * The character `\b`
            * A single character from the list “(25[” `(25[`
            * A character in the range between “0” and “5” `0-5`
    * Or match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) `2[0-4][0-9]`
        * Match the character “2” literally `2`
        * Match a single character in the range between “0” and “4” `[0-4]`
        * Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” `[0-9]`
    * Or match this alternative (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) `[01]?[0-9][0-9]?`
        * Match a single character from the list “01” `[01]?`
            * Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `?`
        * Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” `[0-9]`
        * Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” `[0-9]?`
            * Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `?`
* Match the character “.” literally `\.`
* Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2 `(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)`
    * Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) `25[0-5]`
        * Match the character string “25” literally `25`
        * Match a single character in the range between “0” and “5” `[0-5]`
    * Or match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) `2[0-4][0-9]`
        * Match the character “2” literally `2`
        * Match a single character in the range between “0” and “4” `[0-4]`
        * Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” `[0-9]`
    * Or match this alternative (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) `[01]?[0-9][0-9]?`
        * Match a single character from the list “01” `[01]?`
            * Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `?`
        * Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” `[0-9]`
        * Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” `[0-9]?`
            * Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `?`
* Assert position at a word boundary (position preceded or followed—but not both—by a Unicode letter, digit, or underscore) `\b`
* Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 3 `(]|)`
    * Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) `]`
        * Match the character “]” literally `]`
    * Or match this alternative (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
```

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of regex is unclear. Debuggex makes nice visualization.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/lTI0dtklRtwqwgoT)

The part about 0~255 is clear (000, 00 are also accepted values). But there is unknown reason for trying to match `|)([]` symbols.

I believe first `[` and last `]` appear because of error. Without them the internal regex looks reasonable. But `(|)` and `\b` also don't look right, so my guess is that we can omit `(|)` too.

```
(|)\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b(|)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/wBPimbZURaDbhPjK)